# floating point error in Ruby's BigDecimal class?

Tags: ruby, bigdecimal, floating-accuracy

The universal advice to avoid floating point errors in ruby is to use BigDecimal.  I must be overlooking something, because I think I've found a case where BigDecimal math is returning an error where a Float does not:

using Float gives the correct answer of 2.75:

```
> 50.0 * 0.6 / 360.0 * 33
=> 2.75
```

using BigDecimal gives the incorrect answer of 2.74999999:

```
> BigDecimal("50") * BigDecimal("0.6") / BigDecimal("360") * BigDecimal("33")
=> #<BigDecimal:7efe74824c80,'0.2749999999 999999989E1',27(36)>
```

Someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Is your question why the BigDecimal gives the error, or why the Float doesn't?

Comment: Why does BigDecimal give the error?  And does this example mean that we can no longer trust BigDecimal with our floating point calculations?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/128421. You misunderstand floating point math.

Comment: FWIW, if you can, first multiply before you divide: `BigDecimal("50") * BigDecimal("0.6") * BigDecimal("33") / BigDecimal("360")` and you get your desired result. The answer by @Mladen already tells you why you don't get an exact result if you do it your way. If you first multiply, **the chances are higher** you get an exact result. The line above does `990 / 360` (or `(11 * 90) / (4 * 90)`), which does not produce any repeating decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify your example, and use this one instead:

```
BigDecimal(1) / BigDecimal(3) * BigDecimal(3)
# => #<BigDecimal:19289d8,'0.9999999999 99999999E0',18(36)>
```

How did it get there?

```
BigDecimal(1) / BigDecimal(3)
# => #<BigDecimal:1921a70,'0.3333333333 33333333E0',18(36)>
```

BigDecimal does not provide rational numbers, so when you divide 1 by 3, you get 0, following by a lot of 3s. A lot, but not infinitely many. When you then multiply that by 3, you will get 0 followed by equally many 9s.

I believe you misread the BigDecimal's advertisement (although I am not sure it is anywhere advertised as the solution to floating point errors). It just provides arbitrary precision. It is still a floating point number. If you really want exact numbers when dividing numbers, you might take a look at `Rational` class:

```
(Rational(50) * Rational(0.6) / Rational(360) * Rational(33)).to_f
# => 2.75
```

Comment: Since 2.1 the `r` suffix can be used: `50r * Rational(0.6) / 360r * 33r`.

Comment: Thank you Mladen.  I'm writing a financial app, and considered all the following types for representing money:

* Integer, storing amounts in cents: no good because we need to be able to store fractions of a cent.

* Money gem: uses integer, so same problem as integer.

* Float: prone to floating point errors.

* BigDecimal: less prone to floating point errors (but now I find, still prone to errors in one of our use cases!)

Maybe Rational is the answer then..

Comment: Another solution which seems to work for me: BigDecimal("50") * BigDecimal("0.6") * BigDecimal("33") / BigDecimal("360")
This is based on a comment in the thread that Jordan marked this a duplicate of:
Actually, the key to doing such calculations accurately isn't using fixed-point arithmetic, but rather arranging calculations to avoid having to round values which are going to be scaled up. For example, to charge someone for 17 days of a 30 day month, multiply the monthly amount by 17 and then divide by 30, rather than dividing by 30 and multiplying by 17. – supercat Oct 1 '14 at 15:13